# How a thread can be used to save data in database using Hibernate?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been asked one question in interviews again and again. 
e.g If there are 10000 records in a csv file, how can I access those records using thread and how effectively I can use threading concept to save records in database. 
If i i am using 50 threads each thread will save 200 records. But then what if any one thread in those 50 thread fails. How can i can rollback all the records inserted by other 49 threads ?

Comment: My question would be, why to have 50 threads ? Two thread are enough for such small amount of data. One who read, and the second who "push" to the data base.
Is the question given like this, with 50 threads ?

Comment: Hibernate bring more complexity. Without it, Spring batch + Pure JDBC will be very easy. As for rollback other 49 threads work. Why you need, you only need rollback that failed thread as each thread have been allocate different dataset already, right?

Comment: The number of records are not fixed. Number of records might be 1M or 100M.  I have to have multiple threads (if i am not wrong).

Comment: Interviewer gave me a scenario, that he wants to rollback if any thread fails.